# flash as3 jpgencoder not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to take a Screenshot fo the whole stage in flash. Locally it's working perfectly, but in the html preview it doesnt do anything.

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(product.width,product.height);
bitmapData.draw(this.stage);
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
var byteArray:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData);

var fileReference:FileReference=new FileReference();
fileReference.save(byteArray, ".jpg");
```

Comment: FileReference has a restriction, check the documentation. Perhaps you are running into security issues.

Comment: i dont take the stage anymore, i'm going with a movieclip that holds all the elements that i need for the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

As well as BitmapData.draw has a security resctriction. Be sure that all run-time loaded images have permissions in their crossdomain.xml for your domain.